# Perl and hosts file mapping question?

Tags: perl

I have a `hosts` file that looks like this:

```
10.10.10.1 myserver1 myserver1alias

10.10.10.2 myserver2 myserver2alias
```

I'm looking for a way using perl to pass in an argument of `myserver1` and have it return `myserver1alias`, likewise if I pass in `myserver2` it should return `myserver2alias`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[-1] if $F[1] eq "myserver1"' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty way is:

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /myserver1\s+(\w+)$/' path/to/hostfile
```

You might need to do queries similar to this from time to time, so you could probably make a reusable chunk of code to do this for you. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10;

use HostFileParser;

my $host = HostFileParser->parse("path/to/hostfile")

my $server = $host->find(server => "myserver1")

say $server->alias;
```

Of course, I'm not going to "give you teh codez" for all of that. ;)

(These answers assume Perl 5.10, but if you don't have it the changes are just `say $x` => `print "$x\n"`, or `sub say { print "@_\n" }`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(<>){
 if (/myserver1/){
  @s = split /myserver1/,$_,2;
  print $s[-1];
 }
}
```